# how to avoid using recursive function

Tags: javascript

I found an question and would like to try if I can write a better function without using recursive function and while loop.
But I found that I have no idea how to write it better. Is there anyone who can give me some hints or inspire me.

```
function recursivefunction(i, val) {
  if (!val)  val= 0;
  if (i < 2) throw new Error('wrong input');
  if (i === 2) return 1 / i + val;
 
  return recursivefunction(i - 1, val+ 1 / (i * (i -1)));
}


Write a program doing the same calculation without
recursion.
```

Comment: I'd suggest to think about the last two lines.
First: you check if `i === 2` - it's a final condition. So you'll get you're result when it's met.
Second - you decrement existing value of `i` and update the `val`.
So you can simply add the while loop with the condition and inside it just update values for `i` and `val`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function recursivefunction(i, val) {
  if (!val)  val= 0;
  if (i < 2) throw new Error('wrong input');
  if (i === 2) return 1 / i + val;
 
  return recursivefunction(i - 1, val+ 1 / (i * (i -1)));
}

function nonRecursiveFunction(i, val) {
  if (!val)  val = 0;
  if (i < 2) throw new Error('wrong input');
  while(i > 2) {
    val = val + 1 / (i * (i -1));
    i--;
  }
  return 1 / i + val;
}

const recursive = recursivefunction(4, 2);
const nonrecursive = nonRecursiveFunction(4, 2);

console.log(`Recusrive: ${recursive}, nonrecursive: ${nonrecursive}`);
```

To be honest, I'd replace the return statement with `val + 0.5`, because we know that `i` is exactly 2 and we can use a constant value instead of dividing here.